# solving linear recurrence - general solution confusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, numerical-linear-algebra

I've been trying to get my head around this for days. I understand what is going on with the calculation of a linear recurrence and I also understand how the characteristic is obtained.

What is confusion me is the general solution.

The general solution to the recurrence $at(n) + bt(n-1) ct(n-2) = 0$

For a unique root $r$, the general solution is: $t(n) = (A + Bn)  r^n$. For two distinct roots $r_1$ and $r_2$, the general solution is: $t(n) = Ar_1^n + Br_2^n$

What are $A$ and $B$? What do they represent in the linear recurrence and in the general solution

I just can't see it and I need to get it so I can start my discrete math assignment ...

Thanks heaps in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

$A$ and $B$ are related to the initial conditions of the linear recurrence.  To completely solve a linear recurrence of the form: $$at_n+bt_{n-1}+ct_{n-2}=0$$you need $a,b,c$, and also $t_0,t_1$, where the sequence starts. Given initial conditions, you can find a unique $A$ and $B$ that will give an exact solution.

Comment: Thanks. Am I right in thinking that there is a step missing with our tutor giving us the general solution after showing us how to work out the root?  Therefore I'm right to be a bit confused by that step?

Answer (score 1):

A nice way of looking at this is using the techniques in Wilf's "generatingfunctionology" (2nd edition if free on the 'net).

Start with:
$$
u_{n + 2} + a u_{n + 1} + b u_n = c_n
$$
and starting conditoons $a_0$, $a_1$.

Define generating functions $U(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} u_n z^n$ and $C(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} c_n z^n$. You'll have to get $C(z)$ somehow.

Multiply the recurrence by $z^n$ and add for $n \ge 0$, identifying the resulting sums gives:
$$
\frac{U(z) - a_0 - a_1 z}{z^2} + a \frac{U(z) - a_0}{z} + b U(z) = C(z)
$$
Solve for $U(z)$, and split in partial fractions. This will very often give terms of the forms:
$$
\frac{1}{(1 - \alpha z)^m}
  = \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{-m}{n} (-\alpha)^n z^n
  = \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n + m - 1}{m - 1} \alpha^n z^n
$$
Here $\binom{n + m - 1}{m - 1}$ is just a $m - 1$-degree polynomial in $n$:
$$
\binom{n + m - 1}{m - 1}
  = \frac{(n + m - 1) (n + m - 2) \ldots (n + 1)}{(m - 1)!}
$$
You get $u_n$ by picking the coefficient of $z^n$ en each of the sums.

There definitely is a relation between the coefficients in $u_n$, but there isn't any simple formula.

Comment: Thanks, so at least I'm right to be questioning where these come from - I haven't done maths for many years. I guess I have a little way to go to get my head around what is going on with this one, but take some solace in the fact my enquiring mind is enquiring in the right direction at least ;)